# Google App Engine not being accessed via localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.4, app engine sdk 1.7.0, eclipse juno and Java as programming language. The problem is that App runs perfectly well when deployed on appspot but does not work on localhost. When run as web application on port 8888 or any other port (if change it from the configuration), the log represents server is running but when I hit the URL, nothing happens and after some time connection times out. When, debugged it gives the error: `Cannot connect to VM`. Logs from console for both run and debugged are shown below, kindly help me, I have searched all over the 'net but could not find the solution.

**Log when Debugged:**

```
ERROR: transport error 202: handshake failed - connection prematurally closed
ERROR: JDWP: Failed to initialize transport via localhost:49741, trying localhost via 127.0.0.1:49741
ERROR: transport error 202: recv failed during handshake: Connection reset by peer
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

**Log when run:**

```
2012-07-17 19:07:42.504 java[417:407] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2012-07-17 19:07:42.505 java[417:407] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
Jul 17, 2012 2:07:49 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Jul 17, 2012 2:07:50 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed /Volumes/DATA 1/Google App Engine/Java/HelloWorld/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jul 17, 2012 2:07:50 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed /Volumes/DATA 1/Google App Engine/Java/HelloWorld/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
Jul 17, 2012 7:07:52 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at localhost:8888/
Jul 17, 2012 7:07:52 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

**Log when Run from command line:**

```
    Jul 21, 2012 3:23:19 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
    INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
    Jul 21, 2012 3:23:19 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
    INFO: Successfully processed /Volumes/DATA 1/Softwares/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/demos         
    /guestbook/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
    Jul 21, 2012 3:23:19 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
    INFO: Successfully processed /Volumes/DATA 1/Softwares/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.0/demos/guestbook/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
    Jul 21, 2012 8:23:22 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
    INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8080/
    Jul 21, 2012 8:23:23 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
    INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1) If the application has actually started. Enter "ps ax | grep java" in terminal
2) If the application has bound to the port. Install nmap (not sure how to do it on mac) and run it with "nmap localhost". You will see a list of ports and protocols used. If you don't see 8888 with http then something is wrong.

Comment: ps ax | grep java showed alot of things which i didnt understand, i installed nmap and ran it. It showed port 8888 as 8888/tcp open  sun-answerbook

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it from the command line? It looks like you're trying to start it in the debugger as well.. no? Try running from the command line, make sure that works. Then try running it from eclipse with "Run" not "Debug" and make sure that works before trying the debugger. Appengine is a little bit particular...

Comment: Sorry, but how should I run it from command line? I am new in all this.

Comment: have you read through these docs? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver

Comment: what result did you get? Did you make sure the server wasn't running in eclipse already? (close eclipse...)

Comment: yes server wasnt running in eclipse and eclipse was closed. And same log as in eclipse, server started at the port(first on 8080 then i changed it to 8888 via --port) but the url does not load.

Comment: what url are you trying to load?

Comment: Do you have something unusual in your web.xml or appengine.xml? This is pretty basic functionality. Try going through the example here and see if you can get that working: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating

Comment: When I create the new project by selecting google web toolkit, it runs on localserver but i want it without GWT.

Comment: when I hit hit Url in web browser, it keeps on loading and nothing appears and after some time it times out

Comment: What does your output log say?

Comment: When i run the app, this log appears:
`7/20/12 12:24:55.531 AM Firewall: java is listening from ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8888 proto=6
`
This is in console

Comment: Huh. Try turning off the firewall? Apple Menu | System Preferences | Firewall | Security |Firewall

Comment: Dunno man. Try adding more info to the question. What commands exactly are you typing, what is all of the output from the log...

Comment: thats all the info i have, When i run the server, only log which appears because of it is given above. When built from command line, I use: `/path/to dev_appserver.sh --port=8888 path/to war location` Tried without port and other ports too. This dev_appserver.sh is from app engine sdk.

Comment: You should get a *LOT* more on the command line than that 1 line. Are you still getting that firewall message? If you turn off the firewall you shouldn't be seeing that...

Comment: That firewall msg was on console and it does not come when firewall is off. What I got on terminal is different and is lengthy and exceeds the no of characters in this comment box so i am unable to copy it

Comment: Add it to the original post, without it there's no way to help debug.

Comment: I have added it and its almost same as when run from eclipse

Comment: And when you go to http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin you get absolutely nothing but a timeout?

Comment: The url keeps on loading, nothing appears and after a while it gives timeout.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Sounds like you have a problem with the jvm binding to the port, or your browser is trying to connect to a proxy and not allowing you to hit the url. have you tried with curl or wget?

Comment: No, I dont know about curl or wget. I ll google it. Thanks for helping uptil here. I have not found the solution but have learnt various different things :)